# getting image dimensions in imagick

Tags: php, image, imagick

I'm trying to get the dimensions of images that i converted with imagick. This is my code:

```
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$imagick->setresolution(300,300);
$imagick->readimage($this->uploadPath . '/original/test.pdf');
$imagick->writeImages($this->uploadPath . "/large/preview-%d.jpg", false);
```

So i'm reading a multipage pdf file and i'm converting it to seperate jpg files.
What i want is to retrieve the jpg file dimensions from each image. Can i do this in an easy way? Or do i first need to write the images to the disc and then loop through each of them again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about `Imagick::getImageGeometry`? (http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagegeometry.php)

In your case it should look something like this:

```
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$imagick->setresolution(300,300);
$imagick->readimage($this->uploadPath . '/original/test.pdf');

$geometryInfo = $imagick->getImageGeometry();

// now $geometryInfo is an associative array with 'width' and 'height' items in it

$imagick->writeImages($this->uploadPath . "/large/preview-%d.jpg", false);
```

---

**Update:**

If you want to read concrete page from multipage PDF, try to use such trick:

```
$pageIndex = 0; // you can create "for/foreach" loop to go through all pages
$imagick->readimage($this->uploadPath . '/original/test.pdf[' . $pageIndex . ']');
```

Comment: Thats not really working for me. I have a pdf where the 2nd page is wider than the first, but this function returns met the width of the first page instead, also, i would have liked to have the seperate dimensions for each of the images.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer. Maybe now it's more useful